# STM32F410RB Nucleo not reading from serial device

Tags: c++, serial-port, stm32, mbed

I have a 3DR radio telemetry system setup between my laptop and the nucleo board. When the nucleo board acts as the TX, it works perfectly fine but when it is needed to act as a RX, it just doesn't read the serial port. The pc2.readable() function in the code always returns 0.

STM32F410RB code:

```
#include "mbed.h"

#define TX_PIN PB_6
#define RX_PIN PA_10

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX); 
RawSerial pc2(TX_PIN, RX_PIN);

int main() { 
     pc.baud(57600); 
     pc2.baud(57600); 
     pc.printf("STARTING\n"); 
     while(1) { 
          if(pc2.readable())pc.printf("GOT!\n"); 
         } 
       }
```

Laptop code:

```
import serial
import time

board = serial.Serial(port = '/dev/tty.usbserial-DN02136Z', baudrate =   57600, timeout = 3)

time.sleep(3)

while(1):
      board.write("ssende\n")
      time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: If you attach a serial interrupt, does it fire (via `attach()` on the serial object)? If not, then it'd seem that the message is not sent from the computer... Maybe you need to flush?

(Note in serial interrupt you cannot use printf(), see https://os.mbed.com/blog/entry/Simplify-your-code-with-mbed-events/)

Comment: @Jan Jongboom Thanks for your reply! I tried attaching a serial interrupt without the printf as you mentioned but to no avail. Also I noticed that `Serial.readable()` always returns 0 whereas `Serial.writeable()` always returns 1

Comment: The 3DR Radio flashes when I issue the `board.write` in the python code which indicates a successful transmission. Also the receiver radio flashes a dim light to indicate incoming data.

Comment: Could it be that you're using a different physical UART from UART from code?

Comment: What do you mean by a different physical UART? As I mentioned, the board can write to the radio perfectly fine, but it cannot read from it.

Comment: Based on the current bug backlog I don't see any issues with the port for this board. I'd suggest reporting it at [ArmMbed/mbed-os](https://github.com/armmbed/mbed-os) with the relevant version numbers, so ST can take a look at it.